# How to send URL variables programmatically with response from my PHP endpoint

Tags: php, api, http, http-headers, query-string

I have a basic API endpoint set up on my site, which a 3rd party site will use to verify certain info that is entered into a form by the user.

Here's the flow:
1. User is on 3rd party site.
2. User enters info into a form
3. Info is sent to my site's endpoint.
4. My site checks the information and returns a JSON object.

As you can see from #4, my API is currently set up to return a JSON object. After the info is checked, something like this happens:

```
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
```

However, the 3rd party site is only set up to receive URL variables. Is there a way to pass back url variables programmatically? I realize I could theoretically send a new request, but it's not clear to me where that request should go (the internal workings of the 3rd party site aren't well documented), so I'd much prefer to send it as a response.

I hope this makes sense. Please comment if it doesn't. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need more info. What means "receive URL variables"?

Comment: @MrSil: They're expecting the data to come from query string variables like this: `example.com?var1=one&var2=two`

Comment: So you need to send back the request. You may use curl/sockets or simple use file_get_contents("http://host/?var1=$var1&...")

Comment: @MrSil But I don't know how the host is... I'm assuming `host` is a placeholder and not an actual url convention.

Comment: What means "i dont know how the host is" ? host its your example.com

Comment: Right... I DONT'T know who "example.com" is! (This is in the question.) The 3rd party service uses multiple servers, subdomains, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get to send GET/POST parameters in the response, but in the `response body` you can send whatever you want in whatever format you want - and they can use `curl` or `file_get_content` and parse it on their side (3rd party's website).

For example (on the 3rd party's website):

```
//setting a call to your server
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n".
      "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$https_user:$https_password")."\r\n",
    'content' => $body,
    'timeout' => 60
  )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = 'https://'.$https_server;
// Here they call your server
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context, -1, 40000);
// Here you'll parse the $result
```

Comment: I'm not able to control the 3rd party code. So I can't use this method. But I think you answered my question by explaining that what Im trying to do isn't possible (get or post vars). Correct?